# Branch.io link does not open app store if app is not installed

Tags: branch.io

We're using branch.io to create deep links that should:

- Open the app if the app is installed
- Open the App store if the app is *not* installed

Unfortunately the case where the app is not installed does not work for links that we create using the branch.io API.

The following data is sent to the API (POST /v1/url)

```json
{
  "type": 2,
  "data": {
    "$fallback_url": "https://example.com/topic/123",
    "$deeplink_path": "/topic/123",
    "$marketing_title": "Topic Link",
    "~campaign_id": "campaign-123",
    "~ad_id": "ad-123",
    "referredByUserId": "user-123"
  }
}
```

On the branch.io dashboard we configured that when the app is not installed the app store should be openend. But it seems the configuration of the branch.io dashboard is ignored when using the API? **What parameters do I have to set to what in order to redirect users on mobile to the app store if the app is not already installed?**

PS: When I create a "Quick Link" from the branch.io dashboard everything works as correctly. My question is only about the REST API.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Links created via API do not go to stores, when app is not installed. Quick links created in Branch.io dashboard go there. Any solution?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, I was generating dynamic link and adding it as value for *$ios_url* key in the BranchLinkProperties dictionary.

I debugged the deep link structure sent from console and realized my mistake. Just add your app's key-value pairs directly to the dictionary, it should work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).